# LINQ multiple from clauses null value

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

Hi I'm fairly new to this, hope you can help

I found the following SO article which shows how to filter a LINQ query [LINQ to SQL selecting all records which have any word in the string split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644444/linq-to-sql-selecting-all-records-which-have-any-word-in-the-string-split)

What I can't figure out is how to return all results if the filter array is empty. I've tried:

```
  ... = (from string A in lstStrings
                           from string B in strArray
                           where B == null || A.Contains(B) ..
```

and tried including empty string:

```
  ... = (from string A in lstStrings
                           from string B in strArray
                           where B == null || B == "" || A.Contains(B) ..
```

None of which work

**Edit 1:**

I was using the answer from the article here is my actual code

```
string[] filterlist = Regex
                   .Matches(sfilter, @"(?<match>\w+)|\""(?<match>[\w\s]*)""")
                   .Cast<Match>()
                   .Select(m => m.Groups["match"].Value)
                   .ToArray();

var stk = await (from c in ctx.INVENTORY
                            from f in filterlist
                         where f == null || c.DESC.ToUpper().Contains(f.ToUpper())
                         select c).ToListAsync<INVENTORY>();'
```

ctx is my DBEntityContext.

**Edit 2:**

I should mention my code does work almost as expected, if I type a search string it finds what I'm looking for, but if the string is empty I get nothing.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the lstStrings and strArray? Also what do you eventually select using the expression? If you have strArray and lstStrings already defined before the expression you could just throw in an additional `if` statement before the query, am i right?

Comment: @Fixation Hopefully it now makes more sense with my edit, sfilter is the string supplied by the 'Search' TextBox I'm trying to split the search string in order to make the search broader (unless enclosed in speech marks, Regex should sort that out). I could put an if first and have the LINQ without the where clause I just thought there was an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only apply a more restrictive WHERE clause if the filterlist isn't empty like so:

```
var stk = lstStrings;
if (filterlist!=null && filterlist.Any())
{
    stk = stk.Where(a=>filterlist.Any(b=>a.Contains(b)));
}
```

Using your code:

```
string[] filterlist = Regex
                   .Matches(sfilter, @"(?<match>\w+)|\""(?<match>[\w\s]*)""")
                   .Cast<Match>()
                   .Select(m => m.Groups["match"].Value)
                   .ToArray();

var query= ctx.INVENTORY.AsQueryable();
if (filterList!=null && filterList.Any())
{
  query=query.Where(i=>filterList.Any(fl=>i.Contains(fl));
}
var stk = await query.ToListAsync<INVENTORY>();
```

Comment: honestly I can't make sense of this, nothing to do with your answer there's a lot I still don't understand. Editing question, can fit text in here

Comment: @gavsmith Updated my answer with your updated code.  Note that .ToUpper() likely isn't needed if the context refers to a database that does case insensitive matches and it is configured that way (SQL Server is by default).

Comment: That works great!! I'll study it later to make sense of it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using LINQ extensions like this:

```
var result = lstStrings
            .Where(a => strArray == null || !strArray.Any() || strArray.Any(a.Contains))
            .Distinct();
```

You can alternatively of course just use an if statement to short circuit the whole ordeal, like so:

```
if (strArray == null || !strArray.Any())
{
   ... = lstStrings;
}
else 
{
   ... = (from string A in lstStrings
               from string B in strArray
               where B == null || B == "" || A.Contains(B) ..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var stk = ctx.INVENTORY.AsQueryable();
if (filterlist != null && filterlist.Any()){
    filterlist = filterlist.Where(w => w != null).ToArray();
    stk = stk.Where(w => filterlist.Any(a => w.DESC.ToUpper().Contains(a.ToUpper())));
}
```

Comment: This is giving me multiple errors: filterlist = filterlist.Where(w => w != null); gives error Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) and the next line gives Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Data.INVENTORY>' to 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Data.INVENTORY>'

Comment: Can you please add some explanations.